# Getting an error while using where and orderby for fetching record from firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a simple demo app of wall post.

a post contains threee fields
message,postby,posttime

now i  dont want to show user posts who has logged in...I mean to show only other users posts.

following is my code for stream builder widget

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('posts')
                    .where('postby',
                        isNotEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
                    .orderBy('posttime', descending: false)
                    .snapshots(),
```

and its generating following error...

```
The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([posttime]), false]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([postby])" when an inequality operator is invoked.
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 492 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]'
```